# How can I print a webpage line by line in Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, web

All I want to do is print the HTML text of a simple website. When I try printing, I get the text below in raw format with newline characters (`\n`) instead of actual new lines.

**This is my code:**

```
import urllib.request

page = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.york.ac.uk/teaching/cws/wws/webpage1.html', data = None)
pageText = page.read()
pageLines = page.readlines()
print(pageLines)
print(pageText)
```

I've tried all kinds of other stuff and discovered some stuff. When I try to index the `pageText` variable, even after converting it to a string, it does not find any `\n` character. If I try copying the raw text myself with the new lines represented as `\n` and I `print()` that, it converts the `\n` characters into actual new lines which is what I want. The problem is that I can't get that result without copying it myself.

To show you what I mean, here are some HTML snippets:

**Raw text:**

```
b'<HMTL>\n<HEAD>\n<TITLE>webpage1</TITLE>\n</HEAD>\n<BODY BGCOLOR="FFFFFf" LINK="006666" ALINK="8B4513" VLINK="006666">\n
```

**What I want:**

```
b'<HMTL>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>webpage1</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR='FFFFFf' LINK='006666' ALINK='8B4513' VLINK='006666'>
```

I also used:

```
page = str(page)
lines = page.split('\n')
```

and it suprisingly did nothing.
It just printed it as one line.

Please, help me. I am surprised that I found nothing that worked for me. Even on forums, nothing worked.

Comment: `for line in page: print(line.decode('UTF-8'))` or `print(page.read().decode('UTF-8'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is by using pythons requests module. You can obtain it by doing pip install requests (you may have to use sudo if you're not using a virtualenv).

```
import requests

res = requests.get('http://www.york.ac.uk/teaching/cws/wws/webpage1.html')
if res.status_code == 200: # check that the request went through
  # print the entire html, should maintain internal newlines so that when it print to screen it isn't on a single line
  print(res.content)

  #if you want to split the html into lines, use the split command like below
  #lines = res.content.split('\n')
  #print(lines)
```

Comment: Why go through all this trouble when one could just loop over it?

Comment: Because the OP didn't want to loop over it. He wanted a block of html code that was formated and visually showed the newlines. Also, 4 lines of code is hardly trouble.  Why loop over the content to print, when printing the res.content prints the content and in already formatted block?

Answer (score 0):

Your byte string appears to have hard-coded `\n` in it.

For example, can't split on the value initially.

```
In [1]: s = b'<HMTL>\n<HEAD>\n'

In [2]: s.split('\n')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-e85dffa8b351> in <module>()
----> 1 s.split('\n')

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

So, you `str()` it, but that doesn't seem to work either.

```
In [3]: str(s).split('\n')
Out[3]: ["b'<HMTL>\\n<HEAD>\\n'"]
```

But, if you *escape* the new lines it does somewhat work.

```
In [4]: str(s).split('\\n')
Out[4]: ["b'<HMTL>", '<HEAD>', "'"]
```

You *could* use a raw string to split on

```
In [5]: for line in str(s).split(r'\n'):
   ...:     print(line)
   ...:
b'<HMTL>
<HEAD>
'
```

Or, if you don't want the leading `b`, you can `decode` the byte string into a string object you can then split on.

```
In [9]: for line in s.decode("UTF-8").split('\n'):
   ...:     print(line)
   ...:
<HMTL>
<HEAD>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whet you have is not text but bytes. If you want text just decode it.

```
b = b'<HMTL>\n<HEAD>\n<TITLE>webpage1</TITLE>\n</HEAD>\n<BODY BGCOLOR="FFFFFf" LINK="006666" ALINK="8B4513" VLINK="006666">\n'
s = b.decode()  # might need to specify an encoding
print(s)
```

Output:

```
<HMTL>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>webpage1</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="FFFFFf" LINK="006666" ALINK="8B4513" VLINK="006666">
```